# Вопрос о character-sets-dir и кодировках в MySQL

Tags: mysql, кодировка

1. Для чего в конфигурационном файле MySQL (*my.ini*) используется опция `character-sets-dir`?
2. Как я понимаю, значение этого параметра - путь к папке с набором кодировок, и значит ли это, что другие кодировки, не включённые в папку, не будут поддерживаться сервером MySQL?

Например, если у меня установлено следующее значение параметра:

> [mysqld]
>
> character-sets-dir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server
>   5.0/share/charsets/"

А в папке *C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/share/charsets/* нет файла с кодировкой utf-8, то при вставке данных, предварённой командой

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

данные сохранятся в кодировке *latin1* или в какой-то другой кодировке по умолчанию, но не в *UTF-8*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом каталоге лежит файл `Index.xml` в этом файле перечислены все кодировки и их алиасы, поддерживаемые сервером. Часть кодировок внешние и лежат в `*.xml` файлах, часть внутренние (например, utf-8) и вкомпилированы в сам сервер.

Если выполнить команду `SET NAMES` с указанием неизвестной серверу кодировки

```
SET NAMES qqq
```

то сервер вернет ошибку

> ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'qqq'